# Drop rows where all Boolean columns are False - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, filter, drop

How do I drop a row if all rows have the value False? (here it would mean dropping 'kiwi'.)

```
print(df.head())

>   concatenated   category    apple  banana  orange
> 0  apple_banana    two        True    True   False
> 1        apple     one        True   False   False
> 2        banana    one        False   True   False
> 3        kiwi      one        False   False  False
```

Comment: You haven't shown your definition of `df`.

Comment: Updated it just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each row in the `df` and compare the column, if you get 3 `False` then you can `drop` the `row`,

```
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if not row["apple"] and  not row["banana"] and not row["orange"]:
        df.drop(index=index, inplace=True)
```

**Try this also**

```
  df1 = df[~(~(df['banana'])& ~(df['apple']) & ~(df['orange']))]
```

**Answer for your last commend**

```
  boolean_columns = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
  x = " & ".join('~('+x+')' for x in boolean_columns) 
  x = "~("+x+")"
  df1 = df.query(x)
```

Try this

Comment: Is there a more RAM-efficient, general way? I have many columns and rows in reality.

Comment: Could I do this using a list rather than specifying columns?

Comment: You mean, column names as list..?

Comment: Yep like boolean_columns = ['apple ', 'banana', 'orange']